# bidirectional hibernate - org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: error

Tags: java, hibernate

i have 4 tables kode_pos, korwil, user, and wafat. in Korwil class, it hold foreign key from user and give the primary key to kode_pos,
which mean there are 2 mapping in korwil class @OneToOne and @OneToMany,

I got this error

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: org.ppbni.splatter.model.UserAdmin.korwil, referenced property unknown: org.ppbni.splatter.model.Korwil.useradmin` when I run the application ~

this is the erd,

[image]

this is my kode_pos class

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="kode_pos")
public class KodePos implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="kode_pos", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String kode_pos;

    @Column(name="kelurahan")
    private String kelurahan;

    @Column(name="kecamatan")
    private String kecamatan;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="kode_korwil")
    private Korwil korwil;

    /**Setter and Getter Methods**/
}
```

this is my korwil class,

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="korwil")
public class Korwil implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="kode_korwil", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String kode_korwil;

    @Column(name="nama_korwil")
    private String nama_korwil;

    @Column(name="alias_jabatan")
    private String alias_jabatan;

    @Column(name="jabatan_korwil")
    private String jabatan_korwil;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="korwil")
    private Set<KodePos> kodepos;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name="no_dana")
    private UserAdmin useradmin;

    /**Setter and Getter Methods**/

}
```

this is my user class,

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserAdmin implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="no_dana", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String no_dana;

    @Column(name="npp")
    private String npp;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="useradmin", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Wafat wafat;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="useradmin", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Korwil korwil;

    /**other field**//

    /**setter and gettter methods**/
}
```

this is my wafat class,

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="wafat")
public class Wafat implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="kode_wafat", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String kode_wafat;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="tgl_wafat")
    private Date tgl_wafat;

    @Column(name="usia_wafat")
    private int usia_wafat;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="tgl_makam")
    private Date tgl_makam;

    @Column(name="tempat_makam")
    private String tempat_makam;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name="no_dana")
    private UserAdmin useradmin;

    /**Setter and Getter Methods**/
}
```

this is my controller,

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@RequestMapping(value="/user/daftar-anggota-ppbni.html")
public ModelAndView userDaftarAnggotaPPBNI(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{

    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    String nama = request.getParameter("nama");
    String kota = request.getParameter("kota");

    System.out.println(nama);
    System.out.println(kota);

    Query query = session.createQuery("from UserAdmin where (nama_depan = :namadepan or nama_tengah = :namatengah or nama_belakang = :namabelakang) or kota = :kota");
    query.setParameter("namadepan", nama);
    query.setParameter("namatengah", nama);
    query.setParameter("namabelakang", nama);
    query.setParameter("kota", kota);
    System.out.println(query);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List <UserAdmin> result = query.list();

    for(int i=0; i < result.size(); i++){

        model.addObject("result", result);
    }

    session.close();
    factory.close();

    return userDaftarAnggota(model);

}
```

and this is the error,

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: org.ppbni.splatter.model.UserAdmin.korwil, referenced property unknown: org.ppbni.splatter.model.Korwil.useradmin
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:152)
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1686)
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1393)
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1826)
>   at org.ppbni.splatter.web.controller.UserController.userDaftarAnggotaPPBNI(UserController.java:97)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
>   at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: why are you using "MapsId" ?? http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapsId it is used when you want to map id of an Embeddable object.

Comment: And `@GeneratedValue` for `private String no_dana;` in the `UserAdmin` looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

An exception happens while Hibernate generates a database schema by persistent classes.

I have checked your mapping with Hibernate 5 — there was not any such exception (I am not sure in other parts of your code, of course).

I don't know your Hibernate version, looks like Hibernate 4. But anyway, exception rises in this part of the code

```
    PersistentClass otherSide = (PersistentClass) persistentClasses.get( value.getReferencedEntityName() );
    Property otherSideProperty;
    try {
        if ( otherSide == null ) {
            throw new MappingException( "Unable to find entity: " + value.getReferencedEntityName() );
        }
        otherSideProperty = BinderHelper.findPropertyByName( otherSide, mappedBy );
    }
    catch (MappingException e) {
        throw new AnnotationException(
                "Unknown mappedBy in: " + StringHelper.qualify( ownerEntity, ownerProperty )
                        + ", referenced property unknown: "
                        + StringHelper.qualify( value.getReferencedEntityName(), mappedBy )
        );
    }
    if ( otherSideProperty == null ) {
        throw new AnnotationException(
                "Unknown mappedBy in: " + StringHelper.qualify( ownerEntity, ownerProperty )
                        + ", referenced property unknown: "
                        + StringHelper.qualify( value.getReferencedEntityName(), mappedBy )
        );
    }
```

It is a very strange logic to throw `throw new MappingException( "Unable to find entity: " + value.getReferencedEntityName() )` and catch it. And the error message is very confused.

`otherSide` is your `Korwil` and `otherSideProperty` is your `Korwil.useradmin`. Hibernate doesn't consider `Korwil` as an entity. Possible reasons: you don't add it to your mapping, or some problems with scanning packages for entities. You need to figure out why Hibernate considers `UserAdmin` as an entity and `Korwil` not.

Comment: I'm using hibernate 3 :DD, this is bug of hibernate 3??

Comment: @splatter_fadli Don't know. Try to remove associations to `UserAdmin`. Does Hibernate consider `Korwil` as a persistent? You can try to use Hibernate 4 or Hibernate 5 too.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466050/hibernate-caused-by-org-hibernate-annotationexception-unknown-mappedby , is that true??

Comment: @splatter_fadli I am not sure, because of an example in [HHH-5695](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5695) have an `@Id` annotation on the owner of a relation `@Id  @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BAR_ID")  private Foo foo; `

Comment: my mapping is fine in hibernate 5?? the exception showing when I run the my controller, when start the tomcat it's fine

Comment: @splatter_fadli I checked it with Hibernate 5 and it was fine. You configure Hibernate in the `userDaftarAnggotaPPBNI()`, it is a configuration error.